# HTML div display on top of Flash Object

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a flash slideshow with 2 divs overlaying it, one at the top and one at the bottom.

```
<header>
<div id="top-menu">
 <ul>
  <li>Main Menu Link</li>
  <li>Main Menu Link</li>
  <li>Main Menu Link</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<header>
<div id="content">
 <div id="slideshow_wrapper">
  <section id="intro">
   <p>Introduction Text</p>
  </section>
  <section id="slideshow">
   <!--dynamically inserted flash object-->
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Both overlay properly in Firefox/Safari/Chrome, but nothing I try seems to make it work in IE. I'm using [Remy Sharp's HTML 5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) to make the HTML5 mark-up work in lower versions of IE.
What's funny is that the second div, `#intro` overlays correctly, but `#top-menu` always appears behind the` slideshow.

All 3 elements are absolutely positioned with z-indexes explicitly set. No matter how high or low I set them the flash object is always in front of the `#top-menu` element.

I have checked the rendered `<param>` tags and one of them lists `wmode` as `transparent`.

The flash object is dynamically inserted with php through a CMS, so I have no access to the `<embed>` tag that many have suggested adding the `transparent` attribute to.

Comment: You'll need to add wmode="transparent" into the embed tag, sorry.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of something after I wrote out the code. I added a `z-index` declaration on the parent tag of the problem div and it worked. Something to do with the slideshow being in a different parent div and coming after the parent div of the `#top-menu`. It did seem odd how one div was working fine and the other being difficult.

Comment: Actually, I believe it's `wmode: "opaque"` or at least that's what I've had to use in my applications where I have a flash banner and a drop down on top of it.

Comment: I tried changing `wmode` to `opaque` but no difference.

Comment: Please post your full code. It is a combination of z:index, use of position:relative, position:absolute in divs and also wmode. Which works as <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

Comment: add wmode = transparent to  param inside the flash object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;width:50px;height:200px">
    <div class="swf">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/catwalk/flvplayer_novolume_crop_runway7.swf?autoStart=false&file=../catwalk/movies/379_6.flv&repeat=true" width="50" height="200" wmode="transparent">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/catwalk/flvplayer_novolume_crop_runway7.swf?autoStart=false&file=../catwalk/movies/379_6.flv&repeat=true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        </object>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid #333;background:#fff;width:50px;height:25px;bottom:15px">bottom</div>
    <div class="top" style="position:absolute;border:1px solid #333;background:#fff;width:50px;height:25px;top:47px">top</div>
</div>
```

Simply experiment with the bottom:15px and the top:15px - and then remove the border and style the box as you wish. the object code above is not recommend as I am just typing a quick solution for you.

Simply experiment with the bottom:15px and the top:15px - and then remove the border and style the box as you wish. the object code above is not recommend as I am just typing a quick solution for you.

A live example for you, notice the top box over the video: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/x.php

Comment: if I remember correctly, this did not solve the issue, therefore I cannot accept it as the answer.

Comment: Then please post your answer to the solution.